Keeping leading zeros for an int
I am using a Rigol DG 4162 waveform generator, and i want to extract data from it. I am using a USB to RJ45 Either network Adapter and python 3.11 to do this. The problem that I am running into is using the "connect" function. The connect function needs a ip address and a port number to work, string and int types respectively. However, when i put in my port number (0005) as a integer, it removes the leading zeros. This gives me the error "The request address is not valid in its context". My code is the following:
import pyvisa 
import serial.tools.list_ports
import socket

ip_address = 'my_ip_address'
    port = '0005'
    waveform_data = []
    raw_data = []
    sample_rate = 1e6
    
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        socket.connect((ip_address, int(port)))
        s.sendall(b'*IDN?\n')
        response = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print(f"DG$!^@ identification: {response.strip()}")
    
// more data processing stuff. 

I have tried changing my port number to something like "1000" that has no leading zeros, but due to the adapter that I am using, I an unable to do that. I have tried not using a adapter, and the device is unable to connect at all.

How do you know that the error message relates to the absence of leading zeros?

I need to keep the leading zeros so the "connect" function will work properly. The program is thinking that the port number is "5" and not "0005". There is no device at port 5, so it gives the stated error message.
